# TinyMCE in new resource

Tags: ember.js, tinymce

I'm new in Ember.

I try to use TinyMCE in my project.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  Hi
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="editor">
  <form method="post" class="tinymce">
   <textarea></textarea>
  </form>
</script>
```

My app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('editor', function () {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: ".tinymce",
      menubar:false,
      statusbar: false,
    });
  });
});
```

If I open [www.site.com/index.html#/editor1 TinyMCE](http://www.site.com/index.html#/editor1%20TinyMCE) works. If [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) and click link to editor TinyMCE doesn't work (simple textarea).

I tried this:

```
App.TransactionsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'editor',

  didInsertElement: function(){
    tinymce.init({
      selector: ".tinymce",
      menubar:false,
      statusbar: false,
    });
  }
});
```

Nothing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close with your attempt at making a view.  Instead of calling it `TransactionsView`, just call it `EditorView` (and drop the `template` property) and you should be good to go.

```
App.EditorView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    tinymce.init({
      selector: ".tinymce",
      menubar:false,
      statusbar: false,
    });
  }
});
```

Here's a JSBin : http://jsbin.com/UVONuTU/1/edit